# Constant pop-up of print screen on clicking a particular button

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

I am getting a print screen option on clicking a button. I made no changes to the js or HTML file of my webpage to change the onclick() behavior for the botton, I wrote some kind of a print command in the chrome debugger console and since then the pop-up is coming. I don't exactly remember the command. How do I undo this change? On pushing the code to GitHub, this behavior was repeated in the production environment.

Comment: Please describe the problem in more details. What do you mean by print screen option? Can you make a screenshot that represents the problem?

Comment: If you go to any website and press CTRL+P, the print dialog box you get is the same thing.

Comment: I was just having this problem.  I had a print("..."); command in my code instead of a console.log("...");  if this is persisting in your chrome debugger, maybe refresh the page?  Mine was in VS Code

Comment: Especially since you are using Django, remember to use `console.log()` not `print()` in Javascript, happened to me too